# .htacces https:// to http:// redirect not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, opencart

I have a problem. I need temperarly to redirect my stores to http again.

the non ssl and non ww url are working fine but if a https:// is in front of the url it is not redirecting to http://

This is my .htaccess redirect

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
# RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=302]
#RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}[R=302,L]
```

I tried 3 different rules but can't seem to get it redirected. Thus my google serp is hetting the warning page. Bad for business.

Non ssl  http://tinyurl.com/p4zmmtx
SSL  http://tinyurl.com/pteglog

I use opencart 154. All settings are ok. All static urls are ok in the script. I really don't know how to solve or what i'm doing wrong. Hope someone has a hiont or solution..

Comment: Can you show your `VirtualHost` entry for `HTTPS`

Comment: Directadmin virtual host file?

Comment: it's on the main servers ip. No virtual host adds  exept this refference at the end of the ips file ---> NameVirtualHost 164.138.25.247:80
NameVirtualHost 164.138.25.247:443

Comment: "my google serp is hetting the warning " - So, your HTTPS URLs do not actually work? If that is the case then attempting to redirect in .htaccess is not going to work either as the SSL security kicks in first.

Comment: Ok so you say that the certificate needs to be removed? But if so.. how do you remove a ssl from direct admin the right way?